# Is it possible, string length was un-natural number?

Tags: javascript

Is there any possibility that string length could be un-natural number?

for example:

```
var smth = 'xxxx';
```

are there any cases, when `smth.length > 3` was true, but `smth.length >= 4` not?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: There are some edge cases where `string.length` is greater than the strings length, but never in decimal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Comment: Maybe you should explain where this question is coming from instead...

Comment: Non-int value would be a bug: "The number of elements in the String value represented by this String object." http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-string-instances-length

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen and can you tell that situation,when it is greater that its lengths?

Comment: @tazotodua Some unicode characters. Take a look at this article to learn more: [https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode). Why this happens is also addressed in the first link i posted: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

Answer (score 0):

smth.length > 3 means smth.length should be atleast 4 so smth.length >= 4 will always true

Comment: Unless it's possible for `smth.length` to be 3.5, which is the point of the question. I think OP is after an authoritative reference why that would or wouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is impossible, as long as `smth` is of type string.

Every string object has an own `length` property that is always an integer and cannot be changed. From http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-properties-of-string-instances-length:

> ### length
>
> The number of elements in the String value represented by this String object.
>
> Once a String object is initialized, this property is unchanging. It has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my comments it is edge case scenarios, but if you worry then this method can save you:

```js
var unicodeCharacter = '';
console.log("unicodeCharacter.length:", unicodeCharacter.length);
console.log("unicodeCharacter.split().length:", unicodeCharacter.split().length);
```

[String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) creates an array and assigns each character to a place in that array, regardless of the amount of 16-bit code units it takes to describe said character.

From here you simply measure the length of the array.